# How to do blender rendering on aws ec2 instance p2.8x large?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, blender

i have been trying to do rendering on aws ec2 p2.8x large system but when i try to run the command it just fails with different error each time, i dont know if i am doing any step wrong or something.

So how should i go about this? well i am doing this by seeing this post: https://fajrulf.medium.com/how-to-do-blender-rendering-using-amazon-aws-gpu-28d396dc66a9

Well i am doing it like this:
1.Installing Nvidia drivers:
`

```
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/tesla/418.87/nvidia-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1804-418.87.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i nvidia-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1804-418.87.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/nvidia-driver-local-repo-418.87.01/7fa2af80.pub
sudo dpkg -i nvidia-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1804-418.87.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cuda-drivers
```

`

2.Installing Blender`

```
sudo snap install blender --classic
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx libxi6 libxrender1
```

`

3.Script to enable Gui rendering: `

```
import bpy
prop = bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences
prop.get_devices()
prop.compute_device_type = 'CUDA'
for device in prop.devices:
 if device.type == 'CUDA':
    device.use = True
    bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
 scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
```

`

4.Example blender rendering:

```
blender -b file.blend -P script.py -a
```

I am doing like this, if anybody know what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but in his instructions you have to restart the virtual instance in order for the nvidia drivers to be installed then he checks with nvidia-smi from terminal.